# How to check environment variable in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a line:

```
${http_proxy}=  Remove String  %{HTTP_PROXY}  http://
```

In my `test.txt for robot framework`

I'd like this sentence to perform well whether the environ variable HTTP_PROXY is exist.
For now, if the HTTP_PROXY is not exist, it will trigger a fail like this:

```
"Environment variable 'HTTP_PROXY' does not exist"
```

Answer (score 5):

yes, and another solution is :
${http_proxy}=Get Environment Variable   HTTP_PROXY   ${EMPTY}

where ${EMPTY} is a user defined variable for default value

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) to get the value of the environment variable using the `get` method on the `os.environ` dictionary, which lets you supply a default:

```
| | ${HTTP_PROXY}= | Evaluate os.environ.get("HTTP_PROXY", "")
```

The above will set `${HTTP_PROXY}` to the empty string if the environment variable doesn't exist.